# Delete Javascript Element in Runtime

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this code below:

```
<div id="myid_info_barcode" class="myid_print_duo_barcode">
    <canvas width="256" height="256"></canvas>
</div>
```

I want to delete the canvas in runtime. How will I do that in Javascript?

Comment: Get a reference to it, maybe using *querySelector*. Then use `node.parentNode.removeChild(node)`.

Comment: It's not a "JavaScript element". JavaScript does not have elements. It's a "DOM element".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery you can

```
$('#myid_info_barcode').empty();
```

Alternatively with plain javascript

```
document.getElementById("myid_info_barcode").innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: Answers should not be provided that rely on major libraries that are not requested or tagged in the question (such as jQuery).